# java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am solving problems at HackerEarth and I am not able to figure out why my program in running correctly on my command line and giving right result but when running on their code editor it is giving `java.util.NoSuchElementException` exception.

I searched but couldn't resolve it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {
    public static int[][] arr = null;
    public static int[][] dp = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N, M, T;
        int min;
        int count = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        N = scan.nextInt();
        M = scan.nextInt();

        arr = new int[N][M];
        dp = new int[N + 1][M + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
                arr[i][j] = scan.nextInt();   //line 26
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < M + 1; ++i)
            dp[0][i] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N + 1; ++i)
            dp[i][0] = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < N + 1; ++i) {
            for (int j = 1; j < M + 1; ++j) {
                if (arr[i - 1][j - 1] == 0) {
                    min = Math.min(dp[i - 1][j], Math.min(dp[i]
                        [j - 1], dp[i - 1][j - 1]));
                    dp[i][j] = min + 1;
                } else
                    dp[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < N + 1; ++i) {
            for (int j = 1; j < M + 1; ++j) {
                if (dp[i][j] != 0)
                    count += dp[i][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("" + count);
    }//main
}//class
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at TestClass.main(editor_trsource_1429355115_85417.java:26)
```

Answer (score 3):

This means you don't have data from standard input and you are trying to get `nextInt` from the same. You should probably check if you have data to consumer using [hasNextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) like:

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
   //read nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Problem is with I was expecting 4 different inputs as 0 1 0 0 with space separating them but they are expecting 4 different input as 0100 without any spaces.Do you know any way how we can read this inside an array as 4 different inputs?

Comment: you could read as String and then use charAt method on String to get individual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting solution on online comiler in a programming competition try to refresh the browser.